# Item organizer with support for image copy/pasting, list reordering, and tags

Tags: database, knowledge-organization, wishlist

I'm looking for a web app to organize generic "items", that have,

- a link
- one or more images
- some free-form text note

Ideally the web app would also support structured fields that I could sort by.

A typical example would be organizing potential houses/apartments to buy/rent, with the link coming from various real estate sites (so you can't use only one site's "Save"/"Favorite" feature), and the a structured field being the price.

Podio does this almost to a tee, but is [no longer developed and image pasting is not supported](https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200511098-Rich-text-editing-in-podio).

[Evernote doesn't support re-arranging list items](https://discussion.evernote.com/forums/topic/120175-manually-re-arrange-notebooknotestasks/).

Google Keep kinda does it, but you can't reorder the items when you filter by a tag, and it doesn't have structured fields.

Desktop Linux or Windows app would be OK, but web app preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [workflowy](https://workflowy.com). It supports organizing links,
notes in an outline. It supports tagging. But images aren't supported. There exists a [chrome extension](https://github.com/jonleung/workflowy-images) for images, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Now, workflowy supports files and images as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've found the Podio killer - [Notion](https://notion.so).

Its [database feature](https://www.notion.so/Intro-to-databases-fd8cd2d212f74c50954c11086d85997e) supports everything I've asked for, and [the editing experience](https://www.notion.so/Images-83601023414740ef9c79c23c64f80c6b) is much more inline than Podio's.

[image: Notion database]

[image: Notion database views]